# django version 1.8 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute

Tags: python, django

In my models.py I have 3 classes

Project
Finding
FindingType

Relationship between entities:

Project can have 0 to  N Finding. Each Finding has one Finding type.

```
class Project(models.Model):
completed_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
.. and some other attributes

class RA_Finding_type(models.Model):
finding_title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
finding_desc = models.TextField()
remediation_desc = models.TextField()
trc_control_number = models.TextField()
display = models.BooleanField(blank=True)

class RA_Finding(models.Model):
project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
if (not project.completed_date):      # Error here.
   finding_type = models.ForeignKey(RA_Finding_type, limit_choices_to={'display': True},verbose_name='Weakness Type')
else:
   finding_type = models.ForeignKey(RA_Finding_type, limit_choices_to={'display': False},verbose_name='Weakness Type')
```

... other attributes

In admin.py

```
class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
 form = ProjectAdminForm  # For user sort...

 readonly_fields = ('id', ... others)

 inlines = [
            FindingInline,.. other inlines

           ]

class FindingInline(admin.StackedInline):
 model = RA_Finding
 def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
     field = super(FindingInline, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
     if db_field.name == 'project':
         if request._obj_ is not None:
             field.queryset = field.queryset.filter(id__exact = request._obj_.pk)
         else:
             field.queryset = field.queryset.none()
     return field

 extra = 1

 fieldsets = (
     (None, {
        'fields': ('finding_type',
                  ... other fields
                  )
     })),
```

I want to populate finding_type attribute based on completed date.  This is primary for legacy data. Requirement is - for projects with completed date,  display all the finding types else only display finding type where display is set to true.  When I try to do this, I get an error -  'ForeignKey' object has no attribute.  Is there a way to achieve this in Django?  Appreciate all help.

Comment: Are you just trying to set `finding_type` value based on `completed_date`? or is there anything you want to do like showing it in the admin panel, etc.?

Comment: I am only trying to set the finding_type value based on completed_date. In admin.py I have class FindingInline(admin.StackedInline):
     model = RA_Finding 
         fieldsets = ( (None, {
            'fields': ('finding_type',
                      ('risk_id', 'discovery_date',), ... and others.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it when saving a model:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if (not self.completed_date):
            self.finding...
        else:
            self.finding...

        super(Project, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```